# Variable in url in php

Tags: php

I have variable like:

```
$Name = "filedownload-random"
```

The result of variable $Name is random.

Now every visitor will have his own file. How Can I echo variable $Name into that hyperlink?

```
echo 'You Can Download it <a href="http://sample.com/mp/download/variable-should-comehere.zip">Here</a>';
```

Thanks

Comment: Take the time to read the PHP documentation for echo. http://nl3.php.net/echo

Comment: Please [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) before you ask more questions.

Comment: same basic answer as your last question, you really need to study the basics.

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this:

```
echo 'You Can Download it <a href="http://sample.com/mp/download/'.$Name.'">Here</a>';
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot. $Name = "filedownload-random" but in the echo it should come with .zip

Answer (score 0):

Read more about php and then ask :)

```
echo 'You Can Download it <a href="http://address.com/folder/'.$Name.'">Here</a>';
```

- For random number generating, you can use rand() function.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. $Name = "filedownload-random" but in the echo it should come with .zip

Comment: So you need to right more codes, search more you will find what to do ;) for random number generating, you can user rand();

Comment: Do you have any good solution?

Comment: You should research and think before asking, here's what you've asked: `echo 'You Can Download it <a href="http://address.com/folder/'.$Name.'.zip">Here</a>';`

Comment: @user3468831 You have to check the user information at first if you want to give a custom DL link for each user.

Comment: Thank @Biduleohm. I have another solution btw. I put it outside of php code with p tag.

<p>Download <a href="http://sample.com/mp/download/<?php echo  "$Name.mp3"; ?>">Here</a></p>